# mysql query to update field with the value of other field in the same table

Tags: mysql

**I have a table with these fields:**

id_post

meta_key

meta_value

The query should grab the value of "name_value" where "meta_key" match a given text and remove it from the value of "meta_value" where "meta_key" is "sku".

**Let say I have these rows:**

*id_post -- meta_key -- meta_value*

101 -- myCustomText -- train

101 -- sku -- **cartrain**

102 -- myCustomText -- boat

102 -- sku -- **carboat**

**Then after the query is run the results should be:**

*id_post -- meta_key -- meta_value*

101 -- myCustomText -- train

101 -- sku -- **car**

102 -- myCustomText -- boat

102 -- sku -- **car**

**In words the query should do this:**

FOR EACH ROW WITH THE SAME "id_post" SELECT VALUE OF "meta_value" WHERE " meta_key" == "myCustomText" AND SUSTRACT ITS VALUE FROM "meta_value" WHERE "meta_key" == "sku"

Comment: by name_value you mean myCustomText  right ?

Comment: Du you want to update the or select the record?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid deleted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
update demo
set sku = replace(sku, name_variation, '')
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/133696/2)

Or to show the table as desired view

```
select id_post,
name_variation,
replace(sku, name_variation, '') sku
from demo
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18716d/3)

> Edit for updated question

use a join with same table but with additional filter on `on` clause

```
update demo a  
join demo b on (a.id_post = b.id_post and b.meta_key = 'myCustomText' )
set a.meta_value = replace(a.meta_value, b.meta_value, '')
where a.meta_key = 'sku'
```

[Update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec19/1)

```
select *,
replace(a.meta_value, b.meta_value, '') sku
from demo a 
join demo b on (a.id_post = b.id_post and b.meta_key = 'myCustomText' )
where a.meta_key = 'sku'
```

[Select](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83b990/3)

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake with the field. I will delete this question and create a new one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JPashs no worries i am waiting for you to update your OP

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.